# sendmail never send mail. Always deffered

Tags: linux, debian, sendmail, smarthost

I'm working on a debian squeeze domU ( xen virtualized ) called webserv (result of hostname) and want to send mail using sendmail.
The user name of the user logged in the box is: username
I changed the hostname to a FQDN (mydomain.com).
I go with the default sendmail conf (removing the masquerade stuff from /etc/mail/sendmail.mc)
When i try to send a mail using command line ( sendmail ... -f user@mydomain.com receiver@otherdomain.com) the mail is allways deffered:

```
webserv sendmail[3694]: q2P2nP4M003694: Authentication-Warning: mydomain.com: username set sender to user@mydomain.com using -f
webserv sendmail[3694]: q2P2nP4M003694: from=user@mydomain.com, size=2124, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<d9dc266122bf46d87b59e20cbd0c7432@www.mydomain.com>, relay=username@localhost
webserv sm-mta[3695]: q2P2nPOE003695: from=<user@mydomain.com>, size=2315, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<d9dc266122bf46d87b59e20cbd0c7432@www.mydomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
webserv sendmail[3694]: q2P2nP4M003694: to=receiver@otherdomain.com, ctladdr=user@mydomain.com (1001/1001), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32124, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q2P2nPOE003695 Message accepted for delivery)
webserv sm-mta[3697]: q2P2nPOE003695: to=<receiver@otherdomain.com>, delay=00:00:42, xdelay=00:00:42, mailer=relay, pri=122315, relay=26, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred
```

However if i flush the queue (force the mail to be sent), the mail is successfully sent.

I tried to bypass my problem by using my dedicated mail server box (another domU on the same network of this one, running under debian squeeze and using postfix as MTA, working fine) as a smarthost, but the mail never used the smarthost.

So if you have any advices I'll be glad to hear them.
Regards

PS: It is required that the MTA on the webserv domU is sendmail

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem with sendmail-mta, however i found out that postfix use "sendmail" as binary name. So i uninstalled sendmail then installed postfix, which worked fine out of the box.
I specified i wanted sendmail mta because i needed the name of the binary to be sendmail.
So question closed.

Comment: I think you should mark this as an answer in order for it be become closed (not show up under unanswered any more)

Comment: or remove the question and answer all together since it isn't gonna help anyone who wants to use sendmail with an accepted answer like this